Baofeng Cables for Recording Audio
I want to use a USB/rs232 to plug into a program so that i can get the data from it to manipulate it through code instead. Is there any cables out there where i can do this a easy way?
(And if someone knows what libs for C# is good for this kind of stuff please hook me up with that aswell :) )
TLDR: I found out that because i want to record the audio from the baofeng (Which wasn't aparent in the original post) This means i need to use a audio cable instead.

Sounds like you want a Baofeng programming cable - they just show up on a computer as a serial port, so you can just open/ read / write it. However, I don't think there's much documentation on how to do that - looking at the CHIRP source might be your best bet. That's not audio, though - for audio you'll need a sound card to connect PC line in to the Baofeng audio out.

What kind of Baofeng do you have that has either an RS-232 or USB port?

If you want to record audio, notice the plugs on the Baofeng earphone/mic/ptt unit:
]1
Notice the two plugs on the programming cable. One is an output for an external speaker, and the other is the input for an external microphone.
Baofeng earphone, mic, and PTT button]2

My Baofeng UV-5RV2 uses this FTDI radio programming cable. It does not have either an RS-232 or USB port. I'm pretty sure that you can't use it to record data.
I suggest you buy it from either Foscam or Baofeng to avoid a counterfeit cable.
You will need CHIRP software to transfer data to and from your computer.

Looks like another answer is here.

Feel free to fix this. I'm way past my bedtime. :-)
